# Why does a Hamming code contain $2^m-1$ codewords with weight 3?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-designs

I have a question about the following theorem
concerning a relation between error-correcting Hamming codes and Steiner triple designs.

> **Theorem.** If $C$ is a Hamming $(2^m-1, 2^{2^m-1-m}, 3)$ code, and $A$ is the matrix whose columns contain the weight-3 codewords in $C$, then $A$ is the incidence matrix of a Steiner triple system on $(2^m-1)$ varieties.

Note that a Steiner triple has the same amount of varieties as blocks. This means that the incidence matrix $A$ must be *square*, with dimensions $2^m-1$. Because the columns of $A$ are the codewords in $C$ with weight 3, there are $2^m-1$ codewords in the Hamming code with weight 3.

**Question.** Why does a  $(2^m-1, 2^{2^m-1-m}, 3)$ Hamming code contain $2^m-1$ codewords with weight 3?

Comment: It's simply wrong. For $m=4$ the Hamming code has 35 words of weight 3.